# Insert a linked list to a linked list

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory-management, data-structures, linked-list

I wrote this function that inserts another linked list to the existing linked list. The output is correct when I print out the value of "this" object in the function. However, the program encounters run time error when the destructor gets invoked in the end. I figured that the run time error is caused by having 2 pointers pointing to the same address; therefore when one gets de-allocated, another one becomes the dangling pointer.

Is there any ways I can insert another linked list to the existing linked list (in the middle) without causing this problem?

```
void List::insert(const List& otherList, const int &index)
{
    Node* insertion = head;
    int x = index;
    while (x > 0){
        insertion = insertion->next;
        x--;
    }

    if (index == 0){  //this works fine
        otherList.tail->next = insertion;
        *this = otherList;  /*I implemented a copy ctor 
                              that performs deep copy 
                              so this is also fine */
    }
    else{ // this block causes problems
        Node* tmp = insertion->next;
        insertion->next = otherList.head;
        otherList.tail->next = tmp;
    }
    cout << "after the copy\n" << (*this) << endl;
}
```

Comment: After your insertion, both lists refer to the same nodes, which is why your code crashes.  One destructor frees the shared nodes, then the other destructor tries to free them again.  You need to either physically remove the nodes from the source list so they only exist in the destination list, or else you need to deep-copy the *data* of the nodes and not copy the node pointers themselves.

Comment: @Remy, how do I remove source list since it is passed by constant reference... I cannot modify it

Comment: So at the end of this, are you supposed to have two lists -- one list being a concatenation of two lists, and the second list not modified?  That isn't clear in your question.  If it is that the second list is not modified, why not just write a simple loop, calling the (hopefully you coded it) `this->insertNode()` or similar function for each node in the passed-in list?

Comment: yes, *this should be modified in the end of this function. otherList should not therefore it is passed by const reference

Comment: @GuanSummyHuang So if that is the case, do you already have an existing function that inserts a single node into a list?  If you do, why aren't you just calling it in a loop, instead of duplicating its code?  If not, you should have one, where the parameter would be the node to insert "after" and the new data, i.e. `insertNode(Node* insertPoint, int data_for_new_node)`. (assuming the node's data is an int).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't actually. I can implement one though... That function should take the value of the node instead of the node pointer itself right?  like "void List::insertNode(const int &nodeValue)"

Comment: @mvw That could work too... if that is the case then otherList would be passed by reference...

Comment: Well, there is a flaw in your original program.  If you're going to insert additional nodes in your list, you have to create those new nodes.  Nowhere in your function do you create new nodes.  So yes, you need to either write a function and call it that creates and inserts new nodes, or rewrite your attempt to actually create nodes.  Instead, your current code transfers ownership from `otherList` to `this`, and you don't want that.

Comment: Thank you @PaulMcKenzie.  I will try that.

Comment: @GuanSummyHuang `Node* insertNode(Node *after, int data)` where it returns the new node that was inserted.  Then you can write a loop that calls `insertNode`, something like `Node *p = insertion_point_in_this; Node *q = otherList.head; while( q ) { p = insertNode(p, q->data); q = q->next; }`

Comment: You do some `this->insert(list, i)` it should involve a copy of the nodes from `list` to `*this`. If either `*this` or `list` is not used anymore it can then clean up its nodes independent of the other.

Comment: If you want your pointers to share data in C++, they could be shared pointers.  However, you almost certainly do not want operations on one copy to alter the other. So you want to make deep copies.

Comment: How does your copy ctor look? It seems strange that you append this list to otherList and then perform an assignment using deep copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with your code.

One problem is that it is unclear what you expect from the insert-function.

Where is the other list to be inserted? I would assume that index should mean that the head of otherList would become the Node at position index (counting from zero). That is also what your code is doing for index=0 but for index=1 you actually insert **after** the current element number 1. This can be fixed by changing the while, i.e.

```
while (x > 1)
```

Another problem is that you don't check for nullptr before using the pointers. That must be fixed.

Third problem is that you don't get a copy when index > 0.

I'm not sure if your copy ctor is ok as you didn't provide the code.

Here is another approach (insert-function renamed to insert_list_copy_at):

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node() : next(nullptr) {};

    Node(const Node& other)
    {
        next = other.next;

        // Copy other members
    };

    Node* next;

    // other members
};

class List
{
public:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

    void insert_list_copy_at(const List& otherList, int index);
    void insert_node_at(Node* node, int index);
};

void List::insert_node_at(Node* node, int index)
{
    if (index == 0)
    {
        node->next = head;
        head=node;
        if (tail == nullptr)
        {
            tail=node;
        }
            return;
    }

    if (head == nullptr) {/*throw exception - index out of range*/};

    Node* t = head;
    while(index>1)
    {
        t = t->next;
        if (t == nullptr) {/*throw exception - index out of range*/};
    }

    // Insert node after t
    node->next = t->next;
    t->next = node;
    if (tail == t)
    {
        tail=node;
    }
}

void List::insert_list_copy_at(const List& otherList, int index)
{
    Node* t = otherList.head;
    while(t != nullptr)
    {
        // Create new node as copy of node in otherList
        Node* tmp = new Node(*t);

        // Insert in this list
        insert_node_at(tmp, index);

        // Increment index and pointer
        index++;
        t = t->next;
    }
}
```

BTW - consider using std::vector instead of creating your own list.